# Load images into ListView using AsyncTask (while keeping in mind the exception)

Tags: android

I've found a lot of posts explaining how to load images inside a `ListView` using `AsyncTask`, the problem is that all, at least the ones I have found, do it by instantiating and starting an `AsyncTask` every single time the `getView` method is called inside the `ListView` adapter.

I've done this already, all works well, but when I go through the `ListView` really quickly, it throws an exception at `.execute` saying that it refuses to create anymore threads.

So my question is how to overcome this issue while at the same time keep using `AsyncTasks` ? (I could use a single, "normal, Java" `Thread` but the project specifications say I'm not allowed.

Thanks and cheers

Comment: You can also take a look at https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader. Having good configuration with memory caching. :)

Comment: you can also use volley. it handles all that quite well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rather use `IntentService` instead of `AsyncTask` and also cache the images you already downloaded so next time no data needs to be fetched. Or you can take a look at existing projects like [SmartImageView](https://github.com/loopj/android-smart-image-view) that should do all you need

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm currently doing, I'm storing them in local cache . The only problem  is when the `ListView` requests a lot at the same time. On, I'll take a look at `IntentService`, 'never heard of it before. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, it seems this is what I was looking for. Need to read up on it a little more but I think this is it. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I found this very usefull:

```
    class BitmapDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private String url;
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

    public BitmapDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView) {
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    // Actual download method, run in the task thread
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
         // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
         return downloadBitmap(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    // Once the image is downloaded, associates it to the imageView
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (isCancelled()) {
            bitmap = null;
        }

        if (imageViewReference != null) {
            ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[see the complete post here](http://android-developers.blogspot.pt/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html)

Answer (score 2):

I would go for Aquery for Android

```
aq.id(R.id.image1).image("http://www.vikispot.com/z/images/vikispot/android-w.png");
```

Learn more: [android-query - ImageLoading](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading)

or Volley:
[Volley: Easy, Fast Networking for Android](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728)